# Content is not allowed in prolog. Getting this error while building my android project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I am getting this error for last 24 hours. Please help me out of this. I am getting this error after updating dependency versions. I also added Exo player dependency. I don't know what real problem is.

I tried following things:

** Clean and rebuild the project**

** Delete cache files in C:/users/.android/cache**

** Restart android studio**

** Check xml files for encoding schemes**

Here is my build gradle(app) file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.eventscheduling"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1"

    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:19.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0"
// Firebase dependencies
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.6.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:6.2.1'
    // glide libraries
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    // CircleView images
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    // Material dependency
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'

    //Stylable Toast
    implementation 'com.muddzdev:styleabletoast:2.2.3'

    // GraphView dependency
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'

    // Volley library
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
}
```

I am getting this error again and again.
[Build gradle(app)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiRJ0.png)

Here is build gradle(module)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }


    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here is manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.eventscheduling">
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".eventorg.ui.evntOrg_setting" />
        <activity android:name=".eventorg.ui.evntOrg_Package_detail" />
        <activity android:name=".eventorg.ui.evntOrg_Package_create" />
        <activity android:name=".eventorg.ui.evntOrg_emailVerification" />
        <activity android:name=".eventorg.ui.evntOrg_friend_list" />
        <activity android:name=".eventorg.ui.evntOrg_MessageDetail" />
        <activity android:name=".eventorg.mapService" />
        <activity android:name=".util.InternetBroadCastReceiver" />
        <activity
            android:name=".client.ui.client_home"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".eventorg.ui.evntOrg_home"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_evnt_org_home"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapLocation"
            android:label="Map" />
        <activity
            android:name=".eventorg.ui.evntOrg_signUp2"
            android:label="Sign Up" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/splashScreenStyle">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="EventSchedulingSystem" />
        <activity
            android:name=".eventorg.ui.evntOrg_signIn"
            android:label="Sign In"
            android:theme="@style/splashScreenStyle" />
        <activity
            android:name=".eventorg.ui.evntOrg_signUp"
            android:label="Sign Up" />
        <activity android:name=".client.ui.client_signIn" />
        <activity android:name=".client.ui.client_signUp" />

        <service android:name=".eventorg.mapService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this error because version number of my firebase dependencies are not same. I fix this error by changing the version number.